# Ways to call a function on return

Tags: c++

Whenever I have 2 specific functions, one that I want called upon entry of a function, and one that I want called upon return in a function, I usually use a helper class and put the functions that I want called in the constructor and destructor - then just instantiate an object of that class at the beginning of a function. I do this mostly because I don't know how I would avoid placing the function that I want called on return everywhere before a return statement.

I was wondering if there are any alternative, or nicer methods to handling this problem. I am inexperienced, so I don't even know if my method is considered "terrible programming" or not.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?  What necessitates having to call functions at the beginning and return of all of these functions in the first place?

Comment: @Joe: One scenario might be logging, where you want to log everytime you enter/exit a function and want to save yourself some writing. Well, that's what I think at least..

Comment: i do exactly this for logging the path of execution - nothing wrong with this approach afaik

Comment: As an aside, routines should have a minimal number of return statements, so it should not be super-cumbersome to do it manually (though I'm not advocating doing it manually...)  I'd also take the position that logging that is so verbose that it logs every single enter/exit of a function is not particularly useful in most cases.

Comment: I have a queue that I am utilizing for my application. I have a clock ISR set up that performs timing updates as well as certain actions on the queue. However, the queue can be accessed by other functions outside of the ISR in my control software. The way my control system is set up, I don't want the clock ISR to interfere with the Queue while another function is using it (due to problems). However, I also don't want to disable clock interrupts. I simply want to set a global flag (and do other things) upon entry of the enqueue and dequeue functions to indicate that it is currently accessed.

Comment: @Joe; there's always the exception exit point, which might be anywhere, and you can't do that one manually.

Comment: @MHZ: This technique fits perfectly well to the context that you have described. It is historically reffered to as *RAII*, you can see your global flag as a resource that is acquired/released, so acquiring in the constructor and releasing in the destructor is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a fairly common technique. More specifically, the destructor will be called when leaving the scope where the object was initialized, which might be before the function returns. One use of this is with locks, where a helper object is used to do the unlock when it is destroyed.

This is the only way to ensure a function is called in all situations when leaving a scope, including when exceptions are thrown.

One different situation is where you want to instrument your code, which is what profilers (for example) do, which lets you hook into the code without actually calling anything explicitly. But I don't think this is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks. I marked your answer as correct. However, I was wondering if you could elaborate on a situation where a "return" call for the function that I instantiated my class in would not result in the destructor being called.

Comment: @MHZ; I'm simply saying the destructor might have been called earlier, i.e. when leaving the inner scope where it was instantiated. `void x() { {MyHelper x;} std::cout << "Hello World"; }`, here the `MyHelper` destructor will be called before the the `cout <<`.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. If I had "MyHelper x;" instead of "{MyHelper x;}" would the destructor be called upon return from void x() instead?

Answer (score 2):

This is the standard C++ way to do this.  In early C with Classes there used to be a specific feature to specify functions called automatically on entry and exit of various functions, but they were removed in favor of using objects for this approach.